# AngularJS - route template

Tags: angularjs, symfony, routes, http-status-code-404, ngroute

I installed angularJS in my symfony application and i try to load my html-file from my angular-module:

file-structure:

```
app
bin
bower_components
src
vendor
web
    html
        index.html
    app.js
```

my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'web/html/index.html',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl'
    }).
    ...
}]);

app.controller("IndexCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        { id: 1, name: "adfsdf"},
        { id: 2, name: "Susdfsdfsi"},
        { id: 3, name: "Resdfiner"},
        { id: 4, name: "sdfs"}
    ];
}]);
```

But when html-file is loaded, i get "404 - Not Found".

I already tried relative and absolute path:

```
// absolute
templateUrl: 'html/index.html',

// relative
templateUrl: 'web/html/index.html',
```

Both does not work.

Anybody could help me with this issue?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: I was able to get this up and running in Plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/pzge58p6b3nfUylWPsDM), so I'd have to imagine your paths are somehow incorrect.

Comment: So what is the problem, just open dev tools and check what request fails, then just adjust path accordingly.

Comment: i think the main problem is the configuration in symfony2 and i have to write a ".htaccess" - file maybe ?

Comment: Are you able to access these templates outside of angular (i.e. just open a browser and navigate to that resource URL)? If not, then yes, you might have some restrictions in place.

Comment: i am not able to access these templates outside of angular(i.e. in url), so how should i go on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use `templateUrl: '/html/index.html'`, because symfony2 root directory is in folder web